# curl command from commandline runs fine but from python subprocess I get an error

Tags: python, subprocess

If I run the below command using curl, its a success:

```
curl -XPOST 'localhost:9260/icrd_client_1' -d @clientmappings.json
```

This command creates an index in elasticsearch based on json file. I get a pleasant output:

```
{"ok":true,"acknowledged":true}
```

The issue I am experiencing is when running this command from a python script.

Instead of the pleasant output above after executing my script, I get the following output:

```
['curl', 'XPOST', 'http://localhost:9260/icrd_client_1 -d @clientmappings.json']
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--     0
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--     0
curl: (52) Empty reply from server
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./elastic_ops.py", line 57, in <module>
    output = run_curl(command, composed_url)
  File "./elastic_ops.py", line 36, in run_curl
    return subprocess.check_output(cmd)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 544, in check_output
    raise CalledProcessError(retcode, cmd, output=output)
subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command '['curl', 'XPOST', 'http://localhost:9260/icrd_client_1 -d @clientmappings.json']' returned non-zero exit status 52
```

The output is not a oneliner json response as I got from the real curl command from the cmdline. 
I have 2 Quesions:

1) How can I capture the real lovely output command: `{"ok":true,"acknowledged":true}` instead of the jiberish about the network packets transfered etc.

2) What command needs to be sent to the `subprocess` for this to work like a normal cmdline curl command.

I call the python script like this:

```
./elastic_ops.py create icrd_client_1 http://localhost:9260 clientmappings.json
```

And here is the relevant code of my python script:

```
commandline_args = sys.argv

command_type = commandline_args[1]
index_name = commandline_args[2]
base_elasticsearch_url = commandline_args[3]
file_to_index = sys.argv[4] if len(sys.argv) > 4 else None

def run_curl(command, url):
    cmd = ['curl', command, url]
    print 'sending command: '
    print cmd
    return subprocess.check_output(cmd)

# create Index
# curl -XPOST 'localhost:9260/icrd_client_1' -d @clientmappings.json
if (command_type == 'create'):
    print 'About to run '+command_type+' for Index: '+index_name+' from filename: '+file_to_index
    command = 'XPOST'
    composed_url = base_elasticsearch_url + '/' + index_name +' -d ' + '@'+file_to_index
    print 'URL Request Being sent is:'
    print '.... '+ composed_url
    output = run_curl(command, composed_url)
    print 'output:'
    print output
```

Comment: note: your `curl` command can be implemented in pure Python without subprocesses: `from urllib2 import urlopen; output = urlopen('http://localhost:9260/icrd_client_1', open('clientmappings.json', 'rb').read()).read()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to pass the arguments as you pass them in commandline. So you need to pass

```
['curl', '-XPOST', 'http://localhost:9260/icrd_client_1', '-d', '@clientmappings.json']
```

Comment: How can I add to the cmd array the split values of the url?

Comment: @TazMan you're composing the list, you don't need to split the url, just split the arguments :)

Comment: But this appends to the cmd a split up LIST of commands          split_commands = url.split(' ')
    print 'sending command: '
    print cmd.append(split_commands)

Answer (score 3):

You need to run curl command using --silent option, so what ever your curl response will be disable. So you need to execute command like this
Below how to execute python script

curl --silent http://example.com/app/test.py | sudo python -